# Is there any IDE with a Smalltalk-like class browser for Python/Django?

Tags: python, ide

I am working with a Python/Django project and I would like to have Smalltalk-like class browser. Is there any IDE providing such a thing?

Comment: Python and Smalltalk have different paradigms. Python is not an image, and the object model only exists when the interpreter is running and modules have been imported. Smalltalk you edit the running object model to create your programs.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I know what you say but Java does not have an image and there are IDEs providing Smalltalk-like class browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Smalltalk-like class browsers" then. Can you clarify? I don't think a Java class browser is the same as a Smalltalk class browser. Smalltalk is living. Java is static.

Comment: A class browser is a core object of any Smalltalk system, but in a certain way it is just a view that allow to see/browse all the classes in the system/image.
Java does not have a class-browser but Java IDEs do. For example Eclipse provides a view that is very similar to the Smalltalk class-browser. I am looking for something analogous but for Python/Django projects.